# Catch DeadLetters Akka.NET V 1.1.0

Tags: akka.net

I can subscribe to DeadLetters using this Syntax in Akka.Net V 1.0.8

```
 Cluster.Get(Context.System).Subscribe(Self, ClusterEvent.InitialStateAsEvents, new[] { typeof(DeadLetter)});
```

But When i try use this same syntax in V 1.1.0,i get the following exception!

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   Akka.Cluster.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Subscribe to `IClusterDomainEvent` or
>   subclasses, was [DeadLetter]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cluster subscription is used for receiving events associated with a cluster lifecycle. Dead letters (just like other log messages) are published into an event bus, so you'll need to subscribe to it using `Context.System.EventStream.Subscribe(Self, typeof (DeadLetter))`.

*Take into account, that event bus can be only subscribed to locally, from the actors living inside the same actor system.*

Comment: I can receive deadletters by subscribing like this but when i try to get the message what i get is something like this: **MSG: Akka.Cluster.ClusterHeartbeatSender+Heartbeat .**
How can i get the real message which was sent?

Comment: @Thickar http://api.getakka.net/docs/stable/html/AAC2550B.htm - you can get the real message using the `Message` property on `DeadLetter`